# Ubuntu Software doesn't accept a different theme unless some variations of yaru

Tags: themes

Hello recently I settled a different theme on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the only application that didn't accepted it was the Ubuntu Software, but when I open the settings and set some of the default themes available it accepts.Does anybody knows how to fix this problem?